# How to use Left Join with Conditions from Forein Key?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    rec_trans.title,
    rec_trans.description,
    rec.datetime,
    rec.video_url,
    rec.image_preview
```

/*use record and country*/

```
FROM
    record rec, country
LEFT JOIN record_translate rec_trans ON
   country.id =  rec_trans.Country_id  AND rec_trans.Record_id = rec.id
```

I´m getting

## 1054 - Coluna 'country.id' unknown in 'on clause'

I want to create left join with condition `rec_trans.country_id = country_id and rec_trans.record_id  = rec.id`

Comment: @Lamak its not that problem, i already update the post.

Comment: Which table are you wanting to Left Join to? Both?

Comment: You have bad syntax for the joins.

Comment: @JacobBarnes I want to join the rec_trans

Comment: SELECT
    rec_trans.title,
    rec_trans.description,
    rec.datetime,
    rec.video_url,
    rec.image_preview
FROM
    record rec
LEFT JOIN record_translate rec_trans ON
    rec_trans.Record_id = rec.id
INNER JOIN country c ON c.id = rec_trans.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  In your case, use a `CROSS JOIN:

```
FROM record rec CROSS JOIN
     country LEFT JOIN record_translate rec_trans
     ON country.id =  rec_trans.Country_id  AND
        rec_trans.Record_id = rec.id
```

As you have just learned `,` is not exactly the same as `CROSS JOIN`, although both generate Cartesian products.

In particular, the comma does not propagate the symbols for later use in the `FROM` clause.  Hence the unknown column error.  `CROSS JOIN` does allow the columns to be used subsequently in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Please explain CROSS join

Comment: @PauloRodrigues . . . It does what a comma does, but using an explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: He edited the question before your answer, prior to his edit, Country, was not in the FROM list. No idea if his code is what is in the question body originally or currently.

Comment: I can use multiple cross joins??

Answer (score 0):

The comma between these 2 tables **IS** a "cross join"

```
FROM record rec, country
```

But it s far better to use "explicit join syntax", so it should read like this:

```
FROM record rec
CROSS JOIN country
```

A `CROSS JOIN` multiples EVERY row of `record` with EVERY row of `country` (if each table had 10 rows, then, 10 rows X 10 rows = 100 rows). This type of join are very useful for locating "missing information".

You are able to use multiple joins of any type, e.g.

```
FROM record rec
CROSS JOIN country
LEFT JOIN record_translate rec_trans ON country.id =  rec_trans.Country_id
                                    AND rec.id = rec_trans.Record_id
LEFT JOIN another_table2 t2 on country.id = t2.Country_id
LEFT JOIN another_table3 t3 on country.id = t3.Country_id
```

### ----

Your original query mixed 2 styles of joins: an old-fashioned "comma syntax", and, SQL Standard (ANSI) syntax. The rules for processing a mixed styled query processes the SQL Standard syntax first, followed by the older "comma syntax"; With this in mind this was performed first:

```
FROM record rec
LEFT JOIN record_translate rec_trans ON COUNTRY.id =  rec_trans.Country_id
                                        AND rec.id = rec_trans.Record_id
```

But, as you can see from that snippet `country` hasn't yet been joined so that produced the error. By using SQL Standard syntax consistently the joins are processed as expected and country becomes accessible before the left join is processed.

Hence: **you should never mix "comma syntax" and SQL Standard (ANSI) join syntax in a single query**.